# can you recommend me a program that me install my java program and jre and run my java program as an executable file?

Tags: java

I have been googleing and advance installer http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ will let me do all that, but is too expensive, can you recommend me a free alternative program that does the same thing?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

The most well-known free solution is [IzPack](http://freshmeat.net/projects/izpack/).

Answer (score 0):

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is a free and scriptable install system. There are even [tutorials](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aTutorials).